# How To Sync Application Cache when Manual Database Changes

Tags: c#

I'm using multiple Applications WinForm / ASP.NET that use data caching. How can y keep automaticaly my applications in sync when manual database changes accurs ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty: Recycle the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net you could configure sql dependencies, which will refresh the data in the cache when it is changed in the database. This assumes ms sql server, and depending on the version of ms sql asp.net it works with polling vs. receiving a notification.